# SQL to build a list using either EXIST (or NOT EXIST) or a combination of both

Tags: sql, db2, exists

I want to find the list of COMPANYID/USERID combos on the USER table that have at least 1 Account found on the ACCOUNT table, but all Accounts are closed.  (If there are no Accounts (on ACCOUNT) for the CompanyID/UserID (on USER), it should not be in the results). If just one of the Accounts for a CompanyID/UserID (on USER) is OPEN (on the ACCOUNT table), the CompanyID/UserID should not be on the list.

In the example below, ABC/USER3 is the only combo that fits this.  It has 2 accounts (333 & 666) and both are closed.  The rest of the CompanyID/UserID combinations have least 1 ACCOUNT that is OPEN. DDD/USER5 is excluded because 888 is not on the ACCOUNT table.

TABLE: USERS

| COMPANYID | USERID | ACCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | USER1 | 111 |
| AAA | USER1 | 333 |
| ABB | USER2 | 333 |
| ABB | USER2 | 444 |
| ABC | USER3 | 333 |
| ABC | USER3 | 666 |
| BBB | USER4 | 555 |
| CCC | USER4 | 666 |
| DDD | USER5 | 888 |

TABLE: ACCOUNT

| ACCOUNT | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | OPEN |
| 222 | OPEN |
| 333 | CLOSED |
| 444 | OPEN |
| 555 | OPEN |
| 666 | CLOSED |
| 777 | OPEN |

I wrote the original question with table names that I thought would make it easier to follow (instead of the actual DB2 tables I am using)  NB002.NBTBAUTH (is USERS)    NB002.NBTBMF (is ACCOUNT)

This is the SQL I tried to use:

```
SELECT NB002.NBTBAUTH.*, Q.USERID, Q.CNTOPEN
FROM NB002.NBTBAUTH LEFT JOIN (SELECT NB002.NBTBAUTH.USERID,
COUNT(IF(NB002.NBTBMF.ACCOUNTSTATUS = 'OPEN',1,NULL)) AS CNTOPEN 
FROM USERS INNER JOIN NB002.NBTBMF ON NB002.NBTBAUTH.ACCOUNTID
     = NB002.NBTBMF.ACCOUNTID
GROUP BY USERID) AS Q ON NB002.NBTBAUTH.USERID = Q.USERID
WHERE NOT Q.USERID IS NULL AND Q.CNTOPEN = 0;
```

Error message:

> SQLCODE -104    Illegal Symbol "=".

It is the first = that is causing it. I changed it to a < and got the same message for the <.

Comment: Why would there be an account in Users that does not exist in Account?

Comment: Add tag for db platform.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is because the way these tables are updated/cleaned up.

Comment: What if there was a record DDD/USER5/333 - should that record be retrieved?

Comment: If combination of UserID/CompanyID should be considered, why is User4 not returned for CCC/USER4/666?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
WITH 
  USERS (COMPANYID, USERID, ACCOUNT) AS
(
          SELECT 'AAA', 'USER1', '111' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'AAA', 'USER1', '333' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABB', 'USER2', '333' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABB', 'USER2', '444' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC', 'USER3', '333' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'ABC', 'USER3', '666' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'BBB', 'USER4', '555' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'CCC', 'USER4', '666' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'DDD', 'USER5', '888' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
, ACCOUNTS (ACCOUNT, STATUS) AS
(
          SELECT '111', 'OPEN'   FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '222', 'OPEN'   FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '333', 'CLOSED' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '444', 'OPEN'   FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '555', 'OPEN'   FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '666', 'CLOSED' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT '777', 'OPEN'   FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
*/
SELECT U.USERID
FROM USERS U
JOIN ACCOUNTS A ON A.ACCOUNT = U.ACCOUNT
GROUP BY U.USERID
HAVING COUNT (1) = COUNT (CASE A.STATUS WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END)
```

| USERID |
| --- |
| USER3 |

It's not clear what the USER identifier is - if it's `USERID` or `(COMPANYID, USERID)`. If latter, then add `U.COMPANYID` into `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this everyone.  I have made some progress.  It was discovered there is another column I need to factor in and SQL from this thread has gotten me pretty close.  There are some 'warnings' I am getting that are unclear.  I will be posting a new thread shortly